# In a Multi-columnar File - Remove all Trailing 0's from Decimal Numbers in Bash

Tags: regex, sed

Sample Data Below having 2 Lines and Pipe Delimeter-

```
FD|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|15953092491000|2020072122001412161425872467|2088411904346062|05|S|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|2480.000000|CNY|S|在线支付||29.760000|CNY||S|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|2480.000000|CNY||||||

FD|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|15952580397320|2020072022001448541422843472|2088411904346062|05|S|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|1380.000000|CNY|S|在线支付||13.110000|CNY||S|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|1380.000000|CNY||||||
```

I was trying to Use below -

```
sed -r -e 's/\|/||/g' -e 's/(\|[0-9.]+[1-9])0+\|/\1|/g' -e 's/\|\|/|/g'
```

But this is also removing the trailing 0's even before decimal like
212000 to 212 , which i dont want.

I want only the trailing 0's after Decimal to be Removed -
Example-
72.650000 to 75.65

Comment: Expected Output is wherever it finds values with trailing 0's like 29.760000 or 13.110000 within the file , it should remove the trailing 0's from the file to 29.76 and 13.11 and it can be in any column within the "|" delimeted file

Comment: Should `1380.00000` become `1380` or `1380\.` ?

Comment: 1380.00000 should become 1380

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+(\||$)/\1\2/g; s/\.\0+(\||$)/\1/g' file
```

```
FD|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|15953092491000|2020072122001412161425872467|2088411904346062|05|S|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|2480|CNY|S|在线支付||29.76|CNY||S|2020-07-21 05:28:15|+08:00|2480|CNY||||||
FD|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|15952580397320|2020072022001448541422843472|2088411904346062|05|S|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|1380|CNY|S|在线支付||13.11|CNY||S|2020-07-20 15:15:29|+08:00|1380|CNY||||||
```

Here:

- `s/(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+(\||$)/\1\2|/g`: Removes trailing zeroes after 1 or more non-zero digits after dot
- `s/\.\0+(\||$)/\1/g`: Removes all trailing zeroes after dot

Comment: anubhava - the command  set is not working for a specific set of data, can u please check on this

Comment: FX|8610000416196|31008628845|2020-07-19 04:00:00|-04:00||1.1439004|1.1446|1.1373|EUR|241.99|USD|276.8100000
FX|8610000416196|31008628942|2020-07-19 04:00:00|-04:00||1.1439004|1.1446|1.1373|EUR|119.99|USD|137.3400000

Comment: in the above dataset the data remains as is, can u explain why and is not converting

Comment: looks like if the integer is encountered in the last delimeted column it is not considering it and trailing 0's are not removed from the last column